# Vue v-for no data display using Laravel and Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vue-component

Im using `v-for` and `axios` for displaying data but when I run my website, the data wont show but there are no errors in the console and in my vue developer tool, I can see the data in it. Can someone help me?

[image][image]
Users.vue

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Type</th>
                          <th>Created</th>

                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">
                        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.type}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.created_at}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
    </table>

script>
    export default {
       data() {
    return {

      users: {},
      form: new Form({
        id:'',
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        type: "",
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
      loadUsers(){
           axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data));
      }
  },
    created() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.loadUsers()

        }
    }

</script>
```

api.php

```
Route::apiResource('user', 'API\UserController');
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
```

Comment: It works sir!. Can you explain to me why my code isn't working?

Comment: Can you please help me with my other question sir? I need it really. Here is the link. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336689/cant-display-data-in-datatable-using-vue-axios/57337248#57337248)

Comment: You have your `v-for="user in users.data"` .... This is `undefined` because when your axios request completed you assigned `this.users` directly to an array which was `data`. For the v-for to work it needs to loop over the array which was set to `this.users` and NOT the non-existent `this.users.data`

Comment: I tend to not fetch the data on the same component as where you use it, as it causes reactivity issues. Fetch your data one level up, and push it to your component as a prop. This safe guards a lot of loading stuff, like refreshing the page

Comment: ahh. I see sir, thats why it not displays.. Thanks. Do you have another idea about my second question in the link sir? or suggestions? Im new in vue and im sorry

Comment: @Vince I just responded on your other second question. It's the same exact problem as this one.